# VS Code on a linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, linux-mint, vmware, visual-studio-code

I've installed the latest Linux mint version on a VMware virtual machine, and when i'm trying to run/debug i'm having the following error:

`Unable to open 'strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S': File not found (file:///build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S).`

and a"Create file" button, but when i clicked it - i get the following:

`Permission denied writing to file (file:///build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S)`

After searching the web for hours, I figured out that the problem is that for some reason the GDB is not linked to the GNU libc...but i have no idea how to fix it and everything i've tried failed.
I'll be glad  to know why is that happening and how to fix it.
Thank you.